# Can I make a parent class methods private, but allow them to be called by their child classes via inheritance only?

Tags: ruby, inheritance

Let's say I have a three-level inheritance class hierarchy:

```
Building
  ⬑ OfficeTower
  ⬑ House
    ⬑ RowHouse
    ⬑ DetachedHouse
```

I want the `OfficeTower` and `House` classes to inherit a class method from the `Building` class, which will list all child classes. I want to define this method only once, in the `Building` class, but I **don't actually want the method to be publicly available** if called **directly** from the `Building` class.

Here's what I tried:

```rb
class Building

  private

  def self.subclasses
    # list all subclasses
    ObjectSpace.each_object(Class).select { |c| c < self }
  end

end

class OfficeTower < Building
end

class House < Building
end

class RowHouse < House
end

class DetachedHouse < House
end
```

The `subclasses` class method works as expected when called on a child class of `Building`:

```rb
House.subclasses
=> [DetachedHouse, RowHouse] # This is good.
```

I was expecting the `subclasses` method to raise a `NoMethodError` when called directly from the `Building` class. But that didn't happen:

```rb
Building.subclasses  
=> [DetachedHouse, OfficeTower, RowHouse, House] # I expected NoMethodError!
```

Why doesn't `private` work in this case? Is there a better way to make this method unavailable when called directly from the `Building` class? Should I use composition instead of inheritance here (ie make a `Buildable` module with the `subclasses` class method, and include that module in `OfficeTower` and `House`)? This feels messier to me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why doesn't private work in this case?

Because `private` affects only instance methods, not class methods. I normally use `private_class_method` for this

```
  private_class_method def self.subclasses
    # list all subclasses
    ObjectSpace.each_object(Class).select { |c| c < self }
  end
```

Alternatively, you can define this method in a singleton class where it will be an instance method.

```
class << self
  private

  def subclasses
    # list all subclasses
    ObjectSpace.each_object(Class).select { |c| c < self }
  end
end
```

Note that the privateness is inherited and you won't be able to call the method on `House` either. I would leave the method public and raise from it if `self` is `Building`

```
  def self.subclasses
    raise 'use a subclass' if self == Building

    # list all subclasses
    ObjectSpace.each_object(Class).select { |c| c < self }
  end
```

Comment: Thanks - I decided to use your final suggestion and simply check to see whether `self` is the parent class, and raise an error if it is.

Comment: Another option would be to use the `Class#inherited` hook to add that method to the inheriting classes only and then the method would not exist for `Building` at all. Sidenote: this would also allow accumulation of subclasses and avoid ObjectSpace all together which as the application grows will result in slower and slower looping